# Queue and topic hybrid

Tags: java

I am trying to find a solution that'd be a combination of a queue and a topic. 
What I mean by that is that I want to be able to pull a message from a topic as many times as I want, but also get the update as it arrives. I don't want the topic to die as soon as all the subscribes got the message.

I am looking to implement this in java and have it available across several machines.

Comment: Might want to check Kafka... but this question needs more clarity on what and why as I suspect it'll be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont if that's for a web application or something else , but supposing it was a web app , subscribers has their accounts , ***and each time someone subscribes his account is added to your subscribers_list on your server***

So having a topics list , when a client choose a topic he gets the message , and he should be notified about that ( as i undertsand from your question ) when it arrives , for this i can suggest you to use ***design pattern called observer*** , you will implement it on the client program so when a message arrive he gets a notification , the good side about this design pattern is that it works without a loop or a thread that keep watching

I dont know if that's what you really mean , waiting for your feedback anyway

Comment: Hi Mohamed, What I want to achieve is to be able to read whatever is written on this topic as many times as I want. I also want to be notified when the value of the topic changes. I have read a bit more and I am trying to implement durable subscribers now. In theory, this should fulfil what I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the design pattern observer will help you much in the notification , it's always better , you're welcome @IonutAlinNeagu